# How to update an existing tables datetime column with current datetime in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have an existing sqlite database with a table in it something like this:

```
+------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|LogID |  UsedOn  |     UserID         | Other fields() |
+------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|  1   |          |    soemid03        |  SomeDataHere  |
+------+----------+--------------------+----------------+
Etc....
```

The UsedOn field is currently blank, because when I made the table I accidently forgot to set the field type to a timestamp type, so the application was just inserting the other colums and leaving this one blank.

Because I would like to use a comparison at some point later using the timestamp, I would like to update this column for all rows in the table with the current timestamp, I assume I can use datetime() in sqlite to do this. It does not matter too much that some of the dates and times will be out by a few days, but the field cannot be empty or my comparison code would not work.

I tried using:

```
UPDATE tablename SET UsedOn=datetime()
```

And this was accepted as a valid query, but it seems to do nothing, this column is still empty.

perhaps I'm doing this wrong in some way?

I can only edit the database/table via either manual queries or by using 'SQLite Administrator' app (from http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). I can't use anything else because that is what is available and I'm not allowed to install any other database management tools. When I try to edit any row in the table to add a datetime manually, it does not get accepted, but I just assume this is because the app is trying to insert what I type as a string (even though the format is correct) and it's not a string field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in SQLite Administrator and it does not work, while it should.
What does work is:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET UsedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This does not mean that your code is wrong.
If you use any other tool like [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org), both solutions would work.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I just tried what you put above, but something else must be wrong, because it still does not work for me. I click the 'run query with result' button, it says it's executed with Xms but I then go to the edit data tab to view the table and the UsedOn column is still empty.

Edit: Would it make any difference that when I first made this column, it was just a NAVCHAR(40) type and empty, then I used the edit table function to make it the correct type?

Comment: Further comment for clarity as I'm runing out of characters and it's probably relvant for anyone else who uses this crappy software. I closed and re-opened the database file in SQLite Adminsitrator and then the changes showed up. So it did infact work, but just was not displaying the updated data. Thanks very much for your help @forpas

Comment: @Anseur What is odd is that by using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP the code worked without any need for any refresh. I just executed `select * from tablename`. But with `datetime()` it did not work. In any case I executed `select sqlite_version()` and it seems that SQLite Administrator is using a very old version of SQLite: 3.5.1 while the current version is 3.34.00